# Edit replaygain info (advanced) option missing in foobar2000

Tags: foobar2000, replaygain

When I right-click on a file in foobar2000 and select ReplayGain, there are four options:

1. Scan per file
2. Scan single album
3. Scan by tags
4. Remove info

What I do not see is `Edit replaygain info (advanced)`.

According to many tutorials, it should be there, but it isn't. Has that option been removed from later foobar2000 versions? I am using version 1.0.3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To enable more replay gain context menu options go to:

> File » Preferences » Display » Context Menu » ReplayGain

I had previously been using a 0.9.6.x or some such and also missed the change to the default preferences.

I'm using foobar2000 ver. 1.1.7

Answer (score 1):

It's still there.  Go to Properties->Context Menu->ReplayGain

This will open a list of items to see when right clicking in foobar2000.  In addition to adding "Edit ReplayGain Info" I'd recommend checking the box for "Scan Selection as Albums (by Folder)".  This can be quite useful.